# Getting TypeError when fetching data from custom table and sho in grin in admin panel in magento2

Tags: php, magento

getting error CRITICAL: TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory.php on linecreating a grid in admin panel

Comment: I meant to vote to close as "needs debugging details" but accidentally clicked on the "typo" close reason.

Comment: does this issue have been resolved?

Comment: @FawadSaboor No, the issue is not resolved. The question still lacks [debugging details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Agreed. 
Alright in the admin grid what are you listing? products? 
if yes then please check your database table "catalog_product_entity"
there must be some schemas (SKU , created_at) that you are listing in your grid but empty in the table.

Comment: I am not listing product. its a custom table which has customer data from session.

Comment: @gunjanchaturvedi did you check with the table values?

Comment: Issue has been resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an invalid configuration in my custom listing XML. I showed an integer from the table into my listing columns as follows

```
 <column name="increment_id">
  <settings>
    <filter>text</filter>
    <dataType>int</dataType>
    <label translate="true">ID</label>
    <visible>true</visible>
  </settings>
</column>
```

But this `dataType: int` is invalid. Presumably this field is only required for special cases like `select` and `date` but I did not research further. When I removed that one line it started working again